# Comments are not saving from frontend in django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, web

Hi everyone the comments are not working with CBV my form not even saving the comment. here is my code i will love if anyone help me with this.my models.py is

```
    class Product(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=110)
        slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
        price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6)
        discount_price=models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
        size = models.CharField(choices=SIZE_CHOICES, max_length=20)
        color = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image_path)
        description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
        featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

        objects=ProductManager()

        def get_absolute_url(self):#i use this in product_list.html to go to detail page
            #return "/product/{slug}".format(slug=self.slug)
            return reverse("products:detail", kwargs={"slug" : self.slug})


        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.title)

        @property
        def name(self):         #sometime in html i say name istead of title so to make it work i wrote this
            return self.title

    def product_pre_save_reciever(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):#i inherit unique slug generator from utils to here so when i create aa new instance it slug automatically generate. and i i create two t shirts it give a random straing to tshirt 2nd slug
        if not instance.slug:
            instance.slug=unique_slug_generator(instance)

    pre_save.connect(product_pre_save_reciever, sender=Product)


    class Comment(models.Model):
        product=models.ForeignKey(Product , related_name="comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        body=models.TextField()
        date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return '%s - %s'%(self.product.title, self.name)
```

my forms.py is:

```
    from django import forms
    from .models import Comment

    class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Comment
            fields = ['name', 'body']

            widgets ={
                'name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
                'body':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            }
```

the views.py is:

```
    class CommentCreateView(CreateView):
        model = Comment
        form_class = CommentForm
        template_name = 'add-comment.html'
        # fields = '__all__'


        def form_valid(self, form):
            form.instance.product_id = self.kwargs['pk']
            return super().form_valid(form)
        success_url = reverse_lazy('list')
```

my add-comment.html is:

```html
{% extends "base.html"%}
{% load crispy_forms_tags%}
{% block content %}
  <h2 class="text-center">comment here...</h2>
<div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
 <form method="POST">

   {% csrf_token %}
     <fieldset class="form-group">
    {{form|crispy}}
     </fieldset>
<!--     <div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Pubmit</button>-->
<!--     </div>-->
<!--     <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-secondary">-->
     <button class="btn btn-secondary">Add comment</button>
 </form>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

and my urls.py is:

```
    urlpatterns = [
       # path('featured/' , ProductFeaturedListView.as_view()),
        #path('featured/<int:pk>' , ProductFeaturedDetailView.as_view()),
        path('' , ProductListView.as_view(), name= "list"),
        path('new/' , ProductCreateView.as_view() , name="product-create"),
        path('<slug:slug>/update/' , ProductUpdateView.as_view() , name="product-update"),
        path('<slug:slug>/delete/' , ProductDeleteView.as_view() , name="product-delete"),
        #path('product-fbv/' , product_list_view),
        #path('product/<int:pk>' , ProductDetailView.as_view()),
        path('<slug:slug>/comment' , CommentCreateView.as_view() , name="add-comment"),
        path('<slug:slug>' , ProductDetailSlugView.as_view() , name="detail"),

       # path('product-fbv/<int:pk>' , product_detail_view),

    ]
```

and the error comes when I hit post comment is:
[image]

Comment: In form_valid, where does ```self.kwargs['pk']``` come from ?

Comment: sir actually i follow a tutorial from you tube. i know i  should replace pk   with slug  but when i wrote slug it give me error key error slug instead of key error pk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact you don't provide any `pk` keyword argument to your view.

From the urls.py, I can see you have a slug kwargs though. You can then identify the matching product with its slug.

In your views.py, replace:

```
form.instance.product_id = self.kwargs['pk']
```

by

```
form.instance.product = Product.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
```

Explanation:

Here you want to associate your comment with the matching product. So, for that, you use `NameOfModel.objects.get(query)`, which returns one single instance of your model (here Product), matching the `query`. In your case the only way to retrieve the object is getting the keyword argument `slug` from your url and search it on your Product slug field, so here the query is `slug=self.kwargs['slug']`.